# Issue migrating from Jax-rs 1.1 to 2.0 with Java-ee-7.0 for IBM was 9

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, websphere-9

I am working on a project to upgrade my existing application which is developed in JAX-RS 1.1 and running in WebSphere 8.5. Now I am upgrading it to migrating from Jax-rs 1.1 to 2.0 with Java-ee-7.0 for IBM was 9

When i hit from postman 
    https://abczyz.com/rest/Services_V1/SubmitM
    "{"mID":"XYZ654546","barcID":"","ID":"118","Name":"JACKS","CDefectArray":[],"BDefectArray":[]}"

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/SubmitM")
public JSONObject submitM(JSONObject jsonObjectRequest) {

}
```

Expected it to work as in JAX RS 1.1  but didn't work,

```
5/7/19 14:11:53:571 EDT] 0000013d 0(id=120)]    E   Error occurred during error handling, give up!
                                 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Invalid type of value.  Type: [java.util.ArrayList] with value: [[]]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:76)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:371)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.endpoint.AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.invoke(AbstractJaxRsWebEndpoint.java:147)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.handleRequest(IBMRestServlet.java:187)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.doPost(IBMRestServlet.java:145)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.service(IBMRestServlet.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4198)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2208)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1030)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type of value.  Type: [java.util.ArrayList] with value: [[]]
    at com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:241)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.MapDeserializer._readAndBind(MapDeserializer.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:24)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1961)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:889)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils$2.run(JAXRSUtils.java:1362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:696)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1358)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1308)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:847)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:810)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    ... 35 more
```

### Edit - 1

Tried adding

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I have also extended the Application class

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class MyClass extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
        singletons.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

### EDIT 2

we are using com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs20.jar

```
import com.ibm.json.java.JSONArray;
import com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject;
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the JSON you are passing as indicated by the root cause of the exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type of value.  Type: [java.util.ArrayList] with value: [[]]
    at com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:241)`

Can you try without the empty array fields in the JSON?

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan thanks for your reply , removing the empty array part wont help  as the issue exist with filled array 
{"mID":"XYZ654546","barcID":"","ID":"118","Name":"JACKS","CDefectArray":[{"D_I":45,"D_C":"12","DA_C":"58 - 0 - 36 - 00 - Jar","DE_L_C":"pp"}]}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved as per below link

[Exception is thrown when posting JSON in JAX-RS app running on WLP 8.5.5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093671/exception-thrown-when-posting-json-in-jax-rs-app-running-on-wlp-8-5-5-8)